# How to mix two audio files with ffmpeg amerge filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two audio files and I want merge them into one with volume and delay filter. I need insert delay in one audio stream, also change volumes. I have problem with understanding `map` option...

```
ffmpeg -i one.mp3 -i two.mp3 -shortest -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.4[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=5.0[a1]; \
 [0:a]adelay=10000[0:a]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[out]" \
 #wrong 
 -map [a0] -map [a1] -map ["out"] -ac 2 -c:a libfdk_aac output.m4a
```

How to do this correctly?

Comment: how does this command run? Your adelay output is the input and isn't mapped for output in any case. `amerge` merges channels from the input rather than a mixdown.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for responce, I update my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you intend to delay the entire first input by 10000 milliseconds,

```
ffmpeg -i one.mp3 -i two.mp3 -shortest -filter_complex \
"[0:a]adelay=10000|10000,volume=0.4[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=5.0[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[out]" \
 -map "[out]" -ac 2 -c:a libfdk_aac output.m4a
```

(Remember not to include any whitespace after the slash at end of line.)

Comment: It gives me error `The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_3. Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.`

Comment: Paste the full console output of the command into your question.

Comment: Ok, it worked with `amix`. Is there a difference between `amerge` and `amix`?

Comment: amix does mixdown i.e. 2 channel + 2 channel = 2 channel output whereas amerge is 2 channel; + 2 channel = 4 channels